# Ripple Emulator Origin http://127.0.0.1:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin by using HTTPS

Tags: jquery, cordova, ripple

i started used my API via HTTPS protocol, Ripple emulator in each request give me a message

**Ripple Emulator Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin by using HTTPS**

If i used HTTP, everything works fine.

What i must to do to Ripple works with https?

In settings of Ripple is Cross Domain Proxy set to enabled.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

We can bypass cross domain policies while using ripple, in the run command use the following:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --enable-extensions --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=D:\tmp\chromedevuser
```

Thanks to Raymond Cadmen's Blog: I got this code from there, helped me in reducing the effort

Answer (score 0):

You must set the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' in your API, in PHP this can achieved adding header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

There is no need to use HTTPS, but is very important to protect the data transportation.